# adjustbox seems to add unwanted newpage

Tags: adjustbox

I'm trying to set up an article with a very large letter above the title stuff.  The adjustbox command from the same-named package seems nice, but it always adds a newpage after the enlarged box and I can't seem to figure out why or get rid of it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Hello World}
\author{Joe Blow}
\date{Yesterday}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.25\textwidth,center}
A
\end{adjustbox}
\maketitle
\newpage
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: note `\bf`  has not been defined by default in latex since 1993 although article class defines it for compatibility  with documents that are older than that however it doesn't take an argument, so the syntax would be `\bf Hello` not `\bf{Hello}`  It isn't clear what you mean by a newline, here? but the `center` key you are passing to adjustbox makes it full width with centred content (which is why you get overfull box warnings as you have a space either side of that box, and the vertical rules from fbox so it does not fit in the page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\newpage`.  I removed the `\bf` and the results are still the same.  To restate, the large A should appear just above the title stuff on the same page.  Instead, the title stuff appears on the NEXT page.

Comment: This has nothing to do with adjustbox, as you would see with just "A" before \maketitle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `adjustbox`. The `\maketitle` command begins with `\newpage`, and that is what you get. If your big letter is part of the title formatting, then it should be included in a definition of `\maketitle`.

Comment: jinx on you ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're putting the `adjustbox` before `\maketitle` which issues a `\newpage` command before outputting the title.